# jQuery Rendering with Web Workers

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-worker

I understand that Web Workers cannot access the main document DOM, but has anyone successfully tried to build a partial DOM in a Web Worker using jQuery, output the resulting HTML and then attach that to the document DOM?

Did it provide much of a performance improvement over rendering on the UI thread that is worth the extra pain of implementing this in a thread-safe way?

Would this be trying to use Web Workers for something they shouldn't be used for?

Comment: This question is either too broad (you're basically asking for javascript implementation of DOM renderer) or unclear. If it was worth it to render each frame in separate thread, it would be done that way. But all software, not just browsers, renders basic UI in main thread.

Comment: @TomášZato it was less the rendering and more the building of the HTML that I was interested in (I have edited my question). Rather than a full implementation I was interested as to whether this was feasible.

Comment: [HTML5 Web Workers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) the thing to keep in mind is that if you navigate away or the user change the "scope" the result may not be required... but it seams possible if you manage it well...

Comment: @DanDef Then your question is just too broad - sorry. It really now depends how are you going to build the HTML, from what data etc... But remember that whatever method you chose, you'll have to send it over to main thread and convert to actual DOM objects. I posted that as general answer, there isn't much more I could tell you with the information you put in your question.

Comment: @TomášZato You're right, it was a broad question with an expected broad answer. I was mainly interested to see if anyone had any success in building HTML from data passed into a Web Worker without using [ReactJS](https://github.com/web-perf/react-worker-dom) in general and whether the performance gain was worth the increased complexity of the code. I appreciate your response and will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on what kind of HTML are you trying to generate. However there is one big problem you might have overseen. It's not just that you can't access main thread's DOM.

> You **cannot** create `HTMLElement` object instances in worker **at all**.

So even if you go through the trouble of generating the HTML, you will then have to convert it to HTML string or JSON, parse it in the main thread and convert it to DOM object.

The only case when this is worth it is when *generating* the data for HTML is CPU intensive. And in that case, you can just generate the data, send to main thread and display in HTML.

> This is also good approach to keep data processing and visual rendering separate.